Need intuition for dice betting problem
I'm having a little trouble gaining some intuition for this dice betting question:
A and B each take turns rolling a fair six-sided dice. A player wins if they roll a 4 which is followed by a 1 from the other player. Would you prefer to be A or B?
My intuition said A because if I went first, I could roll a 4 and then B could roll a 1, and I would have the potential to win at the very beginning. If I'm B, I'm, in turn, subjecting myself to this possibility.
But the answers say that it is right to be B. I'm not sure why this is the case.

If A doesn't roll a 4, then it essentially restarts with B going first. If A does roll a 4 but B doesn't roll a 1, then it essentially restarts as well.

I perceived an ambiguity in the phrasing of the question. "A player wins... " (which player ?) but the community saw it as unambiguous that Player $A$ wins, particularly considering the words "they" and "other" later in the question.
With this cleared, I agree with OP's intuition that player $A$ has a higher probability of winning as she can win in the very first round.
However, We can confirm the intuition  easily proceeding step by step, using the Markov property that the future depends only on the present state.
Let the probability of $A$ winning from start be $s$, and from the brink of winning be $t$, then by symmetry, the corresponding state probabilities for $B$ will be $(1-s)\;$ and$\; (1-t)$, and a first step analysis gives
$\displaylines{s = \frac56(1-s) +\frac16(t)\\(1-s)=\frac56s +\frac16(1-t)\\ t = \frac16\cdot1 +\frac46s +\frac16(1-t)}$
On solving the system of linear equations, I get
$s = \dfrac{37}{73}$, i.e. P($A$ wins) $= \dfrac{37}{73}$
and taking its complement, P(B wins) $=\dfrac{36}{73}$,
hence it is preferable to be $A$

Is $t$ the chance $A$ wins after rolling a $4$?  Shouldn't the first equation be $s=\frac 56(1-s)+\frac 16t$ because if he doesn't roll $4$ $B$ starts and if he does he wins $t$?

This doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the first equation have a $t$ rather than a $1-t$, vice versa for the 2nd, and a $1-s$ in the third? (Giving $s = 37/73$ rather than 36?)

Also, just intuitively, hard to see how it could be advantage B here, for similar reasons as OP.

@spaceisdarkgreen: The question as written is a bit ambiguous. I have interpreted it as the winner is the first person to roll a $1$ immediately after the other person has rolled a $4$.

"A player wins if they roll a 4 which is followed by a 1 from the other player" sounds like the first person to do that is the loser, not the winner. And I don't see any ambiguity in this aspect.

@RossMillikan: The wording "A player wins if they roll a 4 which is followed by a 1 from the other player." is a bit ambiguous. I have interpreted it as the winner is the first person to roll a 1
immediately after the other person has rolled a 4. If the reverse interpretation was intended, obviously the probabilities would reverse.
. –

@spaceisdarkgreen: English is not my native language, but would it not have been unambiguous if instead of writing "A player wins.." it had been written "Player A wins..." or Player B wins..." ? Anyway, if we go by your interpretation, all we need to do is to flip the probabilities. The basic approach would remain the same.

Sorry for this confusion. The question was given to me in this ambiguous manner. I did provide my interpretation in the question, which is the same as that of @spaceisdarkgreen: Player A wins if they roll a 4 and B follows up with a 1, and vice versa.
Your answer really helps. Thanks so much! And thank you everyone else for this discussion.

I thought the question was clear that if A rolls 4 and then B rolls 1 it is A that wins.

@trueblueanil
Did you have any intuition in choosing the states for your Markov Chain that you did? Or have you just solved a lot of these problems so you know what the best states would be? I'm also trying to learn how to think here. Any suggestions?

@RossMillikan: I perceived an ambiguity, "A player wins... " (which player ?) and because of the answer, interpreted it to mean A wins. I am not saying that your interpretation is unreasonable.

@AbhayAgarwal: The technique used was First step Analysis. You can look it up for guidance.

Your interpretation is simply wrong: the question as posed is unambiguous.

@tkf: I seem to have been mule headed regarding the interpretation of the question, am now convinced by the arguments of the discerning readers , and have adjusted the answer mutas mutandi for conciseness and clarity.

+1 (also) : because (in my opinion) you diagnosed an ambiguity in the posted question.  So, this ambiguity becomes resolved in a math embraces democracy fashion.

Your intuition is correct, player A has a slightly larger probability to win.
This can be seen as an absorbing markov chain.
If we label the states 1 to 6 as:

$A_0$ = A to play and is not in danger of losing by throwing 1.
$A_1$ = A to play and is in danger of losing by throwing 1.
$B_0$ = B to play and is not in danger of losing by throwing 1.
$B_1$ = B to play and is in danger of losing by throwing 1.
$A_W$ = A wins.
$B_W$ = B wins.

Then we can setup the markov chain as follows:
$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&5/6&1/6\\5/6&0&0&0\\5/6&1/6&0&0\\0&0&5/6&0\end{bmatrix}$
$R=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1/6\\0&0\\1/6&0\end{bmatrix}$
The absorbing probabilities can then be computed as $(I_2-Q)^{-1}R=\begin{bmatrix}0.507&0.493\\0.423&0.577\\0.493&0.507\\0.577&0.423\end{bmatrix}$
The starting player is not in danger of losing so the relevant absorbing probability is from $A_0$ to $A_W$, which is 0.507.

A player is in danger of losing, not loosing, but otherwise very nice

Very nice! I also realized that this was a Markov Chain problem when I first attempted it. However, I was not able to come up with a nice state space. Do you have any intuition for how the states for this problem were crafted?

My first idea was to take a total of 4 states, 2 states for player A to play and for player B to play and 2 absorbing states for A won and B won. But then as soon as I started filling in the transition matrix I realized that the transitions also depend on the history of the previous throw. So 2 more states were needed to make it a Markov chain.

That does make sense. Thanks a lot!

You don't need any fancy calculations here: it can't be a disadvantage to roll first, because if you don't roll a $4$ at the first try, your opponent will then have exactly the same chance of winning as you did at the start; but if you do roll a $4$, you have the added chance that your opponent throws a $1$.
So the official answer is wrong.
And so is true blue anil's answer; but that is, I think, due to a perverse interpretation of the rules.

I agree with the community interpretation of the question, have made the minor adjustment needed.

We can view the dice simply as a discrete random sequence with the numbers 1 to 6. The game ends at the first occurrence of the subsequence (...,4,1,...). Player A wins if the index of this occurrence is even. If it is odd, B wins.
The probability to hit the subsequence at index $k=0$ is 1/36.
$$p(0) = \frac{1}{36} \tag{1}$$
At every point in the sequence the probability of the subsequence being next is 1/36 times the likelihood that we actually made it to this point in the sequence. The likelihood at $k=1$ is then
$$p(1) = (1-p(0))\frac{1}{36} = \frac{35}{36^2} < p(0) \tag{2}$$
or more general
$$p(k) = \prod_{n=0}^{k-1} (1-p(n))\frac{1}{36} \tag{3}$$
This is a strictly monotonic sequence, i.e. $p(k) > p(k+1)$. That implies that for any index k the sum of the even indexed probabilities will be larger than that over the odd ones, i.e.
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} p(2k) > \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor} p(2k+1) $$
Hence the starting player has the better odds.
